# Filtering through relationship in views or template

Tags: python, django

I have one simple model called **Product**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And one other model called **ExternalProduct**

```
class ExternalProduct(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    internal_product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        related_name='external_products',
    )
    price = models.IntegerField()
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    store = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['price']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

On the detailed view of the Product, I want to display the price of all ExternalProduct related to the Product. It works all fine with this view

```
# products/views.py
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'
```

and this template

```
 # product_detail.html
 {% extends '_base.html' %}
    {% block title %}{{ product.title }}{% endblock title %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="book-detail">
    <h2>{{ product.get_active_external_products }}</h2>
    </div>
        <div>
        <ul>
            {% for ep in product.external_products.all %}
                <li>{{ ep.price }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

The problem is that I just want to display the price of ExternalProduct which has active=True

Been trying to solve it with a custom method in products views.py

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'

    def get_active_external_products(self):
        return self.external_products.objects.filter(active=True)
```

And a modified for loop inside product_detail.html

```
{% for ep in product.get_active_external_products %}
    <li>{{ ep.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But unfortunately without any success. The site does not crash, just doesn't show anything other than the rest of the html file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with `Prefetch` to filter only active external products. For this you need to override [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method in your view:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("external_products", queryset=ExternalProduct.objects.filter(active=True), to_attr="active_external_products"))
```

Note `to_attr="active_external_products"` part. It tells that active external products will be available as `active_external_products` attribute. So in template you can get them like this:

```
{% for ep in product.active_external_products %}
    <li>{{ ep.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can just override [`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) to insert external products to the context directly:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(****kwargs)
        context["active_external_products"] = self.object.external_products.filter(active=True)
        return context
```

In this case in template you can use `active_external_products` variable name directly:

```
{% for ep in active_external_products %}
    <li>{{ ep.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another similar thing I want to do is to be able to get the ExternalProduct with the lowest price related to a given Product. I guess I can override both get_queryset() and get_context_data(). To use one for the list of prices and one to get the cheapest external product. But you might know a better solution?

Comment: @JonasFagerlund I think it's more convenient to use `get_context_data` for this. You need to add new variable into context `context["cheapest_external_product"] = self.object.external_products.order_by('price').first()`. And now you can use it in template `{{ cheapest_external_product }}`.

Comment: I see, works out well!

I tried to override the `get_queryset()` for the ListView where I want to display a list of the Product title with the price of the cheapest related ExternalProduct. 

The method returns;
`Product.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("external_products", queryset=ExternalProduct.objects.filter(active=True).first(), to_attr="cheapest_external_products"))` 
(ExternalProduct order by price by default) 

But that causes a crash. Is that because query_set expects a set of objects and not just a single one?

Comment: @JonasFagerlund you cannot use `first()` inside `Prefetch`, it should be a queryset there. It's better for you to ask another question otherwise it's hard to help you without additional details.

Comment: Okay. I'll read some docs and see if I can figure it out myself and if not I ask another question.